# Text overflows cell

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs, ragged2e

"Endomorphism" overflows cell even though I have provided a hyphenation for it. What could be the cause of this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, tabularx,  ragged2e,  booktabs} % nice tables
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % left-aligned text with linebreaks in tables
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}X} % right-aligned text with linebreaks in tables
\usepackage{fullpage} % more space
\usepackage[primitives,keys]{cryptocode} % crypto stuff
\providecommand{\sign}{\pcalgostyle{Sign}}
\hyphenation{Endo-morphism}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} LLL *{6}{R} @{}} \toprule
    scheme & id scheme & transform & $\sign$ (kcycles) & $\verify$ (kcycles) & $\pk$ (bytes)  & $\sk$ (bytes) & $\sig$ (bytes) \\ \midrule
    Yoo et. al & SIDH Zk & Unruh & 28,776,000 & 19,679,000 & 336 & 48 & 122,880\\
    GPS & Endomorphism ring & Unruh & & & 192 & 64 & 540672\\
    SQI-Sign & Endomorphism ring & Unruh & 7,676,000 & 142,000 & 64 & 16 & 204\\
    SeaSign & Couveignes-Stolbunov & Fiat-Shamir with aborts & & & 40 & 20 & 12590 \\
    CSI-FiSh & Couveignes-Stolbunov & Fiat-Shamir & 1,744,600 & 964,600 & 32 & 8000 & 263\\
    Lossy CSI-FiSh & Lossy Couveignes-Stolbunov & Fiat-Shamir &  &  & 256 &  & 2405\\\bottomrule
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: It works in LuaLaTeX. `Endo\-morph\-ism` also works in PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: Using `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}` instead of your original definition of the `L` column type alows hyphenation of the first word in a table cell, thus "Endomorphism" will be hyphenated.

Comment: Use `\hspace{0pt}Endomorphism`, because a word needs to be preceded by a space in order to be considered for hyphenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to allow hyphenation of the first word in a table cell, you can add `\hspace{0pt}`, either locally in a single cell or in the definition of your `L` column type to affect all cells in `L` columns.

In the following MWE, I made some more adjustments to improve alignment and readability of the table: I used `\thead` from the `makecell` package to introduce linebreaks in the column headers and `S` type columns from `siunitx` to align the numbers in the last 5 columns. Since the `S` type columns are narrower than the `R` columns, you used before, there is more space available for the first three columns, which helps to get rid of the otherwise overfull boxes there. Lastly, and to provide a visual separation of the individual entries, I added `\addlinespace` from the `booktabs` package. (The horizontal and vertical alignment of the column headers can of course be adjusted.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, tabularx,  ragged2e,  booktabs} % nice tables
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X} % left-aligned text with linebreaks in tables
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}X} % right-aligned text with linebreaks in tables
\usepackage{fullpage} % more space
\usepackage[primitives,keys]{cryptocode} % crypto stuff
\providecommand{\sign}{\pcalgostyle{Sign}}
\hyphenation{Endo-morphism}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} LLL 
                                 S[table-format=8] 
                                 S[table-format=8]
                                 S[table-format=3]
                                 S[table-format=4]
                                 S[table-format=6]@{}} 
  \toprule
    \thead{scheme} 
      & \thead{id scheme} 
        & \thead{transform} 
          & {\thead{$\sign$\\ (kcycles)}} 
            & {\thead{$\verify$\\ (kcycles)}}
              & {\thead{$\pk$\\ (bytes)}}  
                & {\thead{$\sk$\\ (bytes)}} 
                  & {\thead{$\sig$\\ (bytes)}} \\ 
  \midrule
    Yoo et. al     & SIDH Zk                    & Unruh                   & 28776000 & 19679000 & 336 & 48   & 122880 \\ \addlinespace
    GPS            & Endomorphism ring          & Unruh                   &          &          & 192 & 64   & 540672 \\ \addlinespace
    SQI-Sign       & Endomorphism ring          & Unruh                   & 7676000  & 142000   & 64  & 16   & 204    \\ \addlinespace
    SeaSign        & Couveignes-Stolbunov       & Fiat-Shamir with aborts &          &          & 40  & 20   & 12590  \\ \addlinespace
    CSI-FiSh       & Couveignes-Stolbunov       & Fiat-Shamir             & 1744600  & 964600   & 32  & 8000 & 263    \\ \addlinespace
    Lossy CSI-FiSh & Lossy Couveignes-Stolbunov & Fiat-Shamir             &          &          & 256 &      & 2405   \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you this is amazing. the S type for the last column should be S[table-format=6], no?

Comment: @jvdh: That's correct. Thanks for pointing this out, I'll correct my answer.

Comment: I was going to say you beat me to it by seconds, but @egreg left a comment 26 minutes ago. Anyway, great answer!